# Possible to customize FilterProvider at Runtime?

Tags: json, serialization, view, filter, runtime

i'd like to ask if its possible to Customize in a Json Serializing a Filter at Runtime?

My Sourcelooks like:

```
FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
            .addFilter("XXX",SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(JsonFilterSerializer.getInstance().getMyView()));
            String json= mapper.writer(filters).withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);
```

The Solution i need is like:

```
            FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider();
if(x==true)
            filters.addFilter("XXX",SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(JsonFilterSerializer.getInstance().getXXXView()));
            if(y==true)
            filters.addFilter("YYY",SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(JsonFilterSerializer.getInstance().getYYYView()));
            if(z==true)
            filters.addFilter("ZZZ",SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(JsonFilterSerializer.getInstance().getZZZView()));

        String json= mapper.writer(filters).withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);
```

The Thing is i like to add Filter views to my mapper via If. Otherwise i have to add them in each case seperate what i think is very circuitous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution: (a bit messy)

```
String[] xxx= JsonFilterSerializer.getInstance().getxxxView();
FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
                .addFilter("xxxx",SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(xxx))
```

That can be wrapped in a if case to solve the problem, as i did.

Hope it helps.